# Regular Expression matching nested TAGS

Tags: regex, vbscript, nested

Hello I'm trying to match multi-nested quote's blockquotes and transform them back into BBCode
This is what I got so far as far as regex is involved
Converted it back to html entities to be seen on stackedoverflow

> <div class="quoteheader"><div class="topslice_quote">([\s\S]*?)</div></div><blockquote>([\s\S]*?)(?:</blockquote><div class="quotefooter"><div class="botslice_quote"></div></div>){2,})

I'm trying to match this

> <div class="quoteheader"><div class="topslice_quote">Quote</div></div><blockquote>Outside quote is this
> <div class="quoteheader"><div class="topslice_quote">Quote</div></div><blockquote>Inner quote is this</blockquote><div class="quotefooter"><div class="botslice_quote"></div></div>
> </blockquote><div class="quotefooter"><div class="botslice_quote"></div></div>

to generate this

> [quote]Outside quote is
>   this[quote]Inner quote is
>   this[/quote][/quote]

I'm using VBScript 5.5 Regeular Expressions for this. (but this isn't that important)

I really need help on the expression. I've tired using a HTML Parser for this but it turns out to be more difficult then using regex

Comment: Why not use a proper parser instead of trying to hack up regexes?

Comment: Thou shalt not parse html with regular expressions

Comment: well how about this one time.

Comment: [No.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) You'll summon Cthulhu.  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is all you need to do with the parser.

Here's the pseudocode. I don't know your parser so this is the best I can offer.

First find the div tag with the quoteheader class. Get the next sibling.

That is the blockquote tag. Let's call this tag theQuote.

Get the first child of theQuote. It will be a html text item. That is the outer quote.

Get the third child of theQuote. It will be another blockquote tag. Let's call this tag theInner.

Get the first child of theInner. It will be a html text item. That is the inner quote.

Comment: Yes that's how I did it. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

I'm just repeating what's said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not/590789#590789).

Regular Expressions can't match Context Free languages, like groups of tags.  You can't match opening to closing tags, so parsing a block (Especially a nested one) becomes impossible to do **reliably**.

You can certainly build a cludge to help, but there will be situations where it won't work.