# Using multiple regexes to capture matching nested xml tags

Tags: xml, regex

suppose I have an xml file that contains tags nested inside themselves, eg

```
<TAG>one<TAG>two</TAG>one</TAG>
```

From [this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html), I have two examples of regex expressions that don't properly match this string, eg you will get

```
<TAG>one<TAG>two</TAG>
```

which is not balanced. According to Google, it's not possible to find a regex that will parse html correctly, eg [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4383297/3782261) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not/590789).

> Entire HTML parsing is not possible with regular expressions, since it depends on matching the opening and the closing tag which is not possible with regexps.
>
> Regular expressions can only match regular languages but HTML is a context-free language. The only thing you can do with regexps on HTML is heuristics but that will not work on every condition. It should be possible to present a HTML file that will be matched wrongly by any regular expression.

That's a nice clear-cut theoretical answer, but it got me thinking: *would it be possible programmatically, using multiple regexes and/or loops?*

Comment: Sure, but you may hurt yourself. I made [some progress here](http://regex101.com/r/eK4sS8) based on your example. It searches for the deepest elements at a time, you just have to scrap that, leave an identifier, then try to capture again.

Comment: Is this a question for curiousity or because you want to use this to solve a problem? because if the latter there are several XML parsers that are very simple to use.

Comment: what is the sample input and sample output , please be clear

Comment: If you read that answer, consider also reading the comments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not/590789#comment9022045_590789

Comment: @MikeH-R: Just out of curiosity, really. I used the c# xml classes to do what I wanted to do.

Comment: @thg435: thanks, I had missed the comment I assume you were referring to :-)

Comment: glad to hear it, as I said, I would shudder to imagine anyone using this in production, it is interesting how simply and minimally one can make a parser (as long as you don't mind it being incredibly brittle.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple recursive descent xml parser, I'm making it up right now so it will be somewhat rough and ready, writing it in ruby as you didn't specify a language.
DO NOT USE THIS IN PRODUCTION (or anywhere really, this is just for curiosities sake):

```
string = "<TAG>one<OTHER_TAG>two</OTHER_TAG>one</TAG>"
regex_xml_parser = -> string {
  stuff_before = []
  matches = []
  stuff_after = []
  while string =~ />/
    stuff_before << string[ /^[^<]*/ ]
    string.sub!(/^[^<]*/, '')
    matches << string.match(/<([^>]+)>(.*)<\/\1>/)
    string.sub!(/<([^>]+)>(.*)<\/\1>/, '')
    stuff_after << string[ /[^>]*$/ ]
    string.sub!(/[^>]*$/, '')
    p [ stuff_after, "stuff_after" ]
  end
  values = stuff_before + stuff_after + [string]
  return_value = values.clone
  matching_nodes = matches.map { |match| make_matches[match]}
  {values: return_value.select { |x| x != "" },
  nodes: matching_nodes}
}

make_matches = -> match_item {
  {match_item[1] => regex_xml_parser[match_item[2]]}
}

regex_xml_parser[string]
```

Remember, we are essentially building a parser here, so I think it goes without saying that using a parser that already exists is somewhat easier.

Answer (score 3):

Regular expressions are not regular. Many of the major regex flavors allow you to match all kinds of recursive structures.

Thus to match your example in PCRE you could write ([demo](http://regex101.com/r/aO2lN1)):

```
<TAG>(?:[^<>]+|(?R))*</TAG>
```

Without the need for any additional code or regexes. That's not an XML parser tho.

Comment: +1, nice to see you answering a regex question again. In `PCRE` you could even make that a `++` (but of course you know that) :)

Comment: @Unihedron, what do you mean? Sure you can do that. For example, [this works](http://regex101.com/r/wL6eG3): `<(\w++)>(?:[^<>]|(?R))*+</\1>`. @zx81, don't have much time for that lately. :-)

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about the `(?R)` construct, nice.